# Wildcard Server Certificate cannot be saved in IIs

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

I am using a domain wildcard certificate and want to get that installed on a new server.

In IIS Manager > Server Certificate, I use Complete Certificate Request to add the cert and it's showing in the list view. However it will disappear as soon as I refresh the screen by F5.

Is there something wrong so I cannot add it into the IIS Server?

Comment: Stupid question: did you create the certificate request from that new server?

Comment: No, is it necessary? I tried but it prompted for some details, which I am not quite sure.

Comment: That's how a CSR work. They're linked to a specific server. If you could use a CSR generated from a different server, that would be a massive security hole.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a CSR from the server you want to install the certificate on. Whoever your using as the Certificate Authority (where you bought the cert) should have detailed instructions on this.

**Common name** - 
The fully qualitied domain name. In your case, using the wildcard in the URL. For example: *.stackoverflow.com

**Organisation:** -
The registered name of your business. If it's an individual, enter your name.

**Organisation Unit** -
It's optional. I usually put IT or Website.

**City** -
Full name of the city where located. No abbreviations.

**State** -
Same as city.

**Country** -
Two-letter ISO country code.

Click next and on the Cryptographic service provider properties page:

**Cryptographic service provider** -
Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider

**Bit length** -
If this is a new cert, I'm guessing it will be 2048 as that's the minimum length now.